# scrillTop js script not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, scrolltop

i added this script for internal links scroll gestion on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Pour tous les liens commençant par #.
    $("a[href^='#']").click(function (e) {
        // On annule le comportement initial au cas ou la base soit différente de la page courante.
        e.preventDefault();


        // On ajoute le hash dans l'url.
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top - 72
        }, 'slow');

        return false
    });
});
```

The script does not work perfectly. At the first clic, We're going in the right place, but the scroll does not work. However, from the second click, scroll work properly.

Edit:

My html code:

```
<a class="link-icon visible-desktop" href="#home-keyNumbers-section"><img src="{{ asset('/bundles/visualimmersionsite/images/icons/Arrowhead-Down-256-hover.png') }}" alt="Scroller pour mieux nous connaître" /> </a>

<section id="home-keyNumbers-section" name="home-keyNumbers-section" class="designed-section-2 ">
        <div class="container">
            {%  include 'VisualImmersionSiteBundle:Site:templates/key_numbers_template.html.twig' %}
        </div>


    </section>
```

Have you an idea ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle?

Comment: @nils i'm sorry, i don't know what is JSfiddle :s

Comment: to support FF, you should use `$('body, html').animate(...);`. BTW, you should add hash in URL once animation is done, not before

Comment: With http://jsfiddle.net/ you can provide example-code so we are able to look for any mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
```

This is still going to cause the viewport to scroll; it’s more or less equivalent to just clicking the link. You can use [the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) to push a new URL without causing it to be “visited”:

```
history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
```

If you need to support IE8 and earlier, it might work to hold onto the current scroll position:

```
var originalScroll = window.scrollY; // Grab window.scrollX if applicable
window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
window.scrollY = originalScroll;
```

You might have to put the `window.scrollY = originalScroll` in a `setTimeout` with a timeout of `0`, though.

Comment: great, it works now! But I do not understand what made ​​the difference: s You consider as the link already visited in the script, is that correct?

Comment: @MeursaultF: Setting `window.location.hash` is like visiting the link; visiting a link with a hash that points to a real element will scroll to that element by default. `history.pushState` just changes the history state; it doesn’t navigate to the URL you pass it. (This applies for more than just hashes, too; you can use it for any local URL.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Pour tous les liens commençant par #.
    $("a[href^='#']").click(function (e) {

        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - 72
        }, 'slow', function () {
            // On ajoute le hash dans l'url.
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        });

        return false
    });
});
```

Comment: It's ok for firefox :) but i still have the scroll problem